# Using Lm in dlply while sorting by variable

Tags: r, regression, plyr, lm

I have the following data called: `dataframe`

- `planid` (each plan indicated with a number from 1 till 126)
- `US_FRAC` (a value between 0 and 1 for each fund in each year) and
- `market.premium` (a value indicating the market premium for every fund in every year)

For every `planid` I want to do a regression where I regress `US_FRAC` against `market.premium`as I have 10 years of data for every planid.

I used the following code:

```
mods=dlply(dataframe,.('planid'),lm,formula=ADJ_US_FRAC ~ market.premium)
```

I need both the *t*-statistic and the coefficient for every `planid` in a table, but I could only find the code for the coefficient.  I did something wrong as I only get an output with 1 value for an intercept and nothing else.

Comment: Can you give an example we can work with?

Answer (score 0):

removing the quotes in on planid and ADJ_ before usfrac worked for this sample data

```
dataframe <- data.frame(planid=round(runif(1000)*126), US_FRAC=runif(1000), market.premium=rnorm(1000))
dlply(dataframe,.(planid),lm,formula=US_FRAC ~ market.premium)
```

this summary() performs the coef t-tests. You can create dataframes with the fits with something like:

```
C <- ddply(dataframe,.(planid),function(x) {summary(lm(formula=US_FRAC ~ market.premium,data=x))$coefficients['(Intercept)', ]})

Beta <- ddply(dataframe,.(planid),function(x) {summary(lm(formula=US_FRAC ~ market.premium,data=x))$coefficients['market.premium', ]})
```

kind greetings

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and precise answer, it helped me to create the dataframes I needed. However I still get different results from what I get when I do a regular regression on planid=1(e.g. in excell) any explanations or tips?